# How do I integrate Crashlytics into my Android application with JNI/NDK?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have an Android app that has C++ code in it. I am trying to use Crashlytics for error and crash reporting. I am doing it manually instead of using the plugin since it does not seem to be compatible with Android Studio 3.X. I am using the Gradle that comes with the IDE.

I am unable to use `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk())`, since `CrashlyticsNdk()` cannot be resolved. Sticking to `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics())` at least let me do error and crash reporting to Crashlytics from Java. But I am unable to do it from the C++ code.

I have followed the instructions at https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html and #included the native header (http://download.crashlytics.com/android/ndk/crashlytics.h) in my cpp files but the application crashes with a SegFault at any call to context, like `set()` or `log()`. I don't think the `crashlytics_init()` method is working. This might be because libcrashlytics.so is not found because it is not being built. Doing a manual `System.loadLibrary("crashlytics")` from my Java code also fails.

I suspect that this is a build issue, but no errors are thrown during the build process. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - can you share your build.gradle?

Comment: Hello @MikeBonnell. Thank you for the prompt response. The build.gradle is too long to fit in a comment. Can I email it to you?

Comment: Yep, email support(at)fabric(dot)io.